# mysql union like query with multiple table search in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

im trieng to perform a database search for products, which has 6 tables, it all works well untill i put product_subcategory table in use,
it returns same 1 row with loop or duplicate rows (somewhere around 250 rows of same value, maybe because subcategory contains a lot of entries).
product_subcategory contains subcategory_id, category_id, subcategory_name columns. info of products subcategory are stored in products table as subcategory_id in this format (15,24,1,3,8), (so maybe this is where im doing something wrong)

i have tried some variations of IN , OR..but now im stuck..need help
now to give an idea ($branch = 'Tokyo' and $query = 'Mobiles') and lots of subcategories contain word Mobiles..

what i want as final result is that i can return result using

```
    $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* , t4.*, t5.*, t6.* 
    FROM 
    products t1, product_details t2, product_warehouses t3, product_courier t4, product_category t5, product_subcategory t6
    WHERE
    t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND
    t1.warehouse_id = t3.warehouse_id AND 
    t4.destination = t3.warehouse_branch AND
    t1.category_id = t5.category_id AND
    t3.warehouse_branch = ".$branch." AND
    t5.category_name LIKE '%".$query."%' UNION
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* , t4.*, t5.*, t6.*
    FROM 
    products t1, product_details t2, product_warehouses t3, product_courier t4, product_category t5, product_subcategory t6
    WHERE
    t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND
    t1.warehouse_id = t3.warehouse_id AND 
    t4.destination = t3.warehouse_branch AND
    t1.category_id = t5.category_id AND
    t3.warehouse_branch = ".$branch." AND
    t2.product_name LIKE '%".$query."%' UNION
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* , t4.*, t5.*, t6.*
    FROM 
    products t1, product_details t2, product_warehouses t3, product_courier t4, product_category t5, product_subcategory t6
    WHERE
    t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND
    t1.warehouse_id = t3.warehouse_id AND 
    t4.destination = t3.warehouse_branch AND
    t1.category_id = t5.category_id AND
    t3.warehouse_branch = ".$branch." AND
    t1.product_title LIKE '%".$query."%'  UNION
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* , t4.*, t5.*, t6.*
    FROM 
    products t1, product_details t2, product_warehouses t3, product_courier t4, product_category t5, product_subcategory t6
    WHERE
    t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND
    t1.warehouse_id = t3.warehouse_id AND 
    t4.destination = t3.warehouse_branch AND
    t1.category_id = t5.category_id AND
    t3.warehouse_branch = ".$branch." AND
    t6.subcategory_id IN (t1.subcategory_id) AND //i think this is where im lost
    t6.subcategory_name LIKE '%".$query."%' 
    ";
```

i can execute the query properly when i remove the subcategory table from all union..
hope you guys can help me.

im using codeigniter for final result
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();

Comment: hi..sorry i should have mentioned this..i have tried UNION ALL and same result..also tried specifically UNION DISTINCT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is wrong, why did you 6 times add 6 same tables?
Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM 
`products` `p`
JOIN `product_details` `pd` ON `p`.`product_id` = `pd`.`product_id`
JOIN `product_warehouses` `pw` ON `p`.`warehouse_id` = `pw`.`warehouse_id`
JOIN `product_courier` `pco` ON `pco`.`destination` = `pw`.`warehouse_branch`
JOIN `product_category` `pca` ON `pca`.`category_id` = `p`.`category_id`
WHERE
`pw`.`warehouse_branch` = \'' . $branch . '\' AND
`pd`.`product_name` LIKE \'%' . $query . '%\'';
```

Comment: thank you..looks elegant..but main problem im having is with products_subcategory, how to implement csv like values "2,85,4,6" in subcategory_id and how do i join it with other tables?

Comment: exactly the same add `product_subcategory`, add according to the table `products`, and write t6.subcategory_name LIKE '%".$query."%'

Comment: Ok.. im gonna give it a go and will share the results

Comment: `$sql = 'SELECT id, name
FROM 
products p
JOIN product_details pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
JOIN product_warehouses pw ON p.warehouse_id = pw.warehouse_id
JOIN product_courier pco ON pco.destination = pw.warehouse_branch
JOIN product_category pca ON pca.category_id = p.category_id
JOIN product_subcategory ps ON ps.subcategory_id = p.subcategory_id
WHERE
pw.warehouse_branch = \'' . $branch . '\' AND
(pd.product_name LIKE \'%' . $query . '%\' OR
ps.subcategory_name LIKE \'%' . $query . '%\')';`

Comment: its an old project given to me for repairing works like this..i have to maintain the view files in mvc structure so i had to go 6 times with union.if this works i will change the views..thanx

Comment: it works, however anyway to return multiple subcategories? it returns only one subcategory with row while there is atleast 7 to 8 minimum..i can work with php on that...just curiousity

Comment: it returns as much subcategories, as can be found by your query, there is no magic :)

Comment: Just try to analyze like subcategory has id = 1, what product have subcategory = 1 ?, or maybe you lost any warehouse...